# Update text boxes when a property's value changes - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

*The context of this example is there are four text boxes that hold a total amount of time. 1 for hours, 1 for minutes, 1 for seconds, and 1 for milliseconds.*

*There is a fifth text box that holds the total time in just milliseconds. This can be seen in the image below.*

---

I have made an implementation of `IMultiValueConverter` that should convert 4 `TextBox` components and the converted value in a property. It should also be able to update the 4 boxes when the property's value changes.

When the user types in the text box that holds the converted output and then that box loses focus, the other 4 text boxes are updated. However, when the property's value is programmatically changed, in this case by a button click, the values in the 4 text boxes are not updated.

How can I make these 4 text boxes update through the converter?

The ultimate goal, in this example, is to store the total time (in milliseconds) in a property and have 5 text boxes updating through bindings when that property is updated.

This is the code for the converter.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MultiBinding_Example
{
    public class MultiDoubleToStringConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        private const double HOURS_TO_MILLISECONDS = 3600000;
        private const double MINUTES_TO_MILLISECONDS = 60000;
        private const double SECONDS_TO_MILLISECONDS = 1000;
        private const string ZERO_STRING = "0";
        private object valBuffer = null;

        /*
         * values[0] is the variable from the view model
         * values[1] is hours
         * values[2] is the remaining whole minutes
         * values[3] is the remaining whole seconds
         * values[4] is the remaining whole milliseconds rounded to the nearest millisecond
         */

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            object returnVal = ZERO_STRING;
            try
            {
                if (values != null)
                {
                    double hoursToMilliseconds = (values[1] == null || values[1].ToString() == string.Empty) ? 0 : System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1]) * HOURS_TO_MILLISECONDS;
                    double minutesToMilliseconds = (values[2] == null || values[2].ToString() == string.Empty) ? 0 : System.Convert.ToDouble(values[2]) * MINUTES_TO_MILLISECONDS;
                    double secondsToMilliseconds = (values[3] == null || values[3].ToString() == string.Empty) ? 0 : System.Convert.ToDouble(values[3]) * SECONDS_TO_MILLISECONDS;
                    double totalTime = ((values[4] == null || values[4].ToString() == string.Empty) ? 0 : System.Convert.ToDouble(values[4])) + secondsToMilliseconds + minutesToMilliseconds + hoursToMilliseconds;
                    returnVal = totalTime.ToString();

                    if (values[0] == valBuffer)
                    {
                        values[0] = returnVal;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        valBuffer = returnVal = values[0];
                        ConvertBack(returnVal, new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) }, parameter, culture);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException) { }

            return returnVal;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                if (value != null && value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                {
                    double timeInMilliseconds = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);

                    object[] timeValues = new object[5];
                    timeValues[0] = value;
                    timeValues[1] = Math.Floor(timeInMilliseconds / HOURS_TO_MILLISECONDS).ToString();
                    timeValues[2] = Math.Floor((timeInMilliseconds % HOURS_TO_MILLISECONDS) / MINUTES_TO_MILLISECONDS).ToString();
                    timeValues[3] = Math.Floor((timeInMilliseconds % MINUTES_TO_MILLISECONDS) / SECONDS_TO_MILLISECONDS).ToString();
                    timeValues[4] = Math.Round(timeInMilliseconds % SECONDS_TO_MILLISECONDS, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
                    return timeValues;
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException) { }

            return new object[] { ZERO_STRING, ZERO_STRING, ZERO_STRING, ZERO_STRING, ZERO_STRING };
        }
    }
}
```

To test this, I have a quite a simple layout that consists of a few `Label` components, a few `TextBox` components and a `Button`.

It looks like this.

[image]

The XAML for it is the following.

```
<Window x:Class="MultiBinding_Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiBinding_Example"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MultiDoubleToStringConverter x:Key="multiDoubleToStringConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Multi Value Converter" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0, 25, 0, 0"/>
        <Label Content="Formatted Total Time" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Margin="20, 10"/>
        <Grid Margin="80, 10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Name="Hours" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="0"  Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label Content="Hours" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0, 0, 15, 0"/>

            <TextBox Name="Minutes" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Label Content="Minutes" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0, 0, 15, 0"/>

            <TextBox Name="Seconds" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="0" Grid.Column="4"/>
            <Label Content="Seconds" Grid.Column="5" Margin="0, 0, 15, 0"/>

            <TextBox Name="Milliseconds" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="0" Grid.Column="6"/>
            <Label Content="Milliseconds" Grid.Column="7"/>
        </Grid>

        <Label Content="Unformatted Total Time" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Margin="20, 10"/>
        <Grid Margin="80, 10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiDoubleToStringConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                        <Binding Path="TotalTime"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Hours" Path="Text"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Minutes" Path="Text"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Seconds" Path="Text"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Milliseconds" Path="Text"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <Label Content="Milliseconds" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="250, 20" Height="50" Content="Random Total Milliseconds" Click="RandomTime_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The code behind is the following.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace MultiBinding_Example
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private Random random = new Random();

        private string totalTime;
        public string TotalTime {
            get => totalTime;
            set {
                totalTime = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            UpdateTotalTime();
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void RandomTime_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateTotalTime();
        }

        private void UpdateTotalTime()
        {
            double percent = random.NextDouble();
            double time = Math.Floor(percent * random.Next(1000, 100000000));
            TotalTime = time.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, at least on my PC, the image is not being added correctly. I have tried twice but the image will not render in the question. Hopefully this is a server glitch and it will be rendered eventually. In the meantime just press on the link

Comment: I think you need to call `RaisePropertyChanged(TotalTime);` this way, passing the `Property` name?

Comment: @Sach `CallerMemberName` takes care of that

Comment: I see, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really what a converter is for.

Converters take a set of view model values and convert them to view values for display. Then if the *view values* change it can convert them back to view model values.

In your case, the view model value is updated through code (not through a change to the view) and so the converter has no reason to run the `ConvertBack` method (the value is already a view model value!). This is one of several reasons why converters *should not have side-effects*.

The correct way to do this would be to have `TotalTime` as a property on the VM (probably as a number or `TimeSpan` and not a string as you have it) and then do individual converters for each of the pieces. For example:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding TotalTime, Converter={StaticResource TimeSecondsConverter}"/>
```

The main text box would then just be bound to `TotalTime`. `TimeSecondsConverter` would probably need to be a multi-value converter in order for `ConvertBack` to work.

Comment: Okay. But by taking that approach, how would I factor in the other text boxes?

Comment: @Dan That's why it would probably need to be a multi-value converter. The common alternative would be to throw a DP on the converter that always holds the full time so it can be modified appropriately.

Comment: Sorry I meant if `TimeSecondsConverter` was a multi-value converter, how would I link it to the other text boxes using the line `Text="{Binding TotalTime, Converter={StaticResource TimeSecondsConverter}"`? That is why I used xml tags to do the binding instead of it being all in line like that

Comment: @Dan oh, sorry. In the multi-value case you have to do the full tags as you had it.

Comment: Okay. So basically instead of having one converter, I would need 5 (one for each box) to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: @Dan That's right. You need to explicitly bind each box.

Comment: Thanks for the help